Identify this movie about school massacre
I remember seeing a movie in which a woman lives with her children and sees them growing up until she gets a cancer. Her kids help her recovery but at one point we see her youngest daughter being involved and killed in a school massacre. She then start an association named after her daughter. I think it was a true story of a real school massacre (I think there also were some videos of the real attack) based on some memories or book.
Sorry for the vague description, but I think I saw it more than ten years ago and I have never been able to find it. Hope it is enough. 

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

The plot of Dawn Anna (2005) sounds like the one you're searching for.

The movie depicts the life of Dawn Anna, a teacher and single mother of four children. Soon after meeting her eventual husband, she is diagnosed with a severe brain disease that requires a serious operation. Shortly after her recovery, daughter Lauren Townsend is murdered in the Columbine High School massacre.

The wiki page of the Columbine High School massacre in popular culture confirms this:

Dawn Anna - The story about Lauren Townsend's mother and her life, including her struggles with cancer and eventual recovery, which is soon shattered by the death of her daughter in the shooting.

